# using variable to make variable name in shell script

Tags: shell

I want to echo $ANMIAL0 and then $ANIMAL1 using a script below.
But I get `line 7: ${ANIMAL$i}: bad substitution` error message. What's wrong?

```
#!/bin/sh
ANIMAL0="tiger"
ANIMAL1="lion"
i=0
while test $i -lt 2; do
echo "Hey $i !"
echo ${ANIMAL$i}
i=`expr $i + 1`
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the shell normally performs a single substitution pass. You can force a second pass with `eval`, but this obviously comes with the usual security caveats (don't evaluate unchecked user input, etc).

```
eval echo \$ANIMAL$i
```

Bash has various constructs to help avoid `eval`.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably better off using an array instead of `ANIMAL0` and `ANIMAL1`. Something like this maybe?

```
#!/bin/bash

animals=("Tiger" "Lion")

for animal in ${animals[*]}
do
    printf "Hey, ${animal} \n"
done
```

Using `eval` will get you into trouble down the road and is not best practice for what you're trying to do.

Comment: Well, if you do end up using this method instead please mark this as the correct answer. Other than that, glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eval`

```
eval echo \$ANIMAL$i
```